# Using Texture Atlas as Texture Array in OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, texture-mapping, opengl-3, voxel

I'm now building a Voxel game. In the beginning, I use a texture atlas that stores all voxel textures and it works fine. After that, I decided to use Greedy Meshing in my game, thus texture atlas is not useful anymore. I read some articles which said that should use Texture Array instead. Then I tried to read and use the texture array technique for texturing. However, the result I got was all black in my game. So what am I missing?

This is my texture atlas (600 x 600)

[image]

Here is my Texture2DArray, I use this class to read and save a texture array

```
Texture2DArray::Texture2DArray() : Internal_Format(GL_RGBA8), Image_Format(GL_RGBA), Wrap_S(GL_REPEAT), Wrap_T(GL_REPEAT), Wrap_R(GL_REPEAT), Filter_Min(GL_NEAREST), Filter_Max(GL_NEAREST), Width(0), Height(0)
{
   glGenTextures(1, &this->ID);
}

void Texture2DArray::Generate(GLuint width, GLuint height, unsigned char* data)
{
   this->Width = width;
   this->Height = height;

   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, this->ID);

   // I cannot decide what the texture array layer (depth) should be (I put here is 1 for layer number)
   //Can anyone explain to me how to decide the texture layer here? 
   glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 1, this->Internal_Format, this->Width, this->Height, 0, 1 , this->Image_Format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);

   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_S, this->Wrap_S);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_T, this->Wrap_T);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_WRAP_R, this->Wrap_R);

   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, this->Filter_Min);
   glTexParameteri(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, this->Filter_Max);
   
   //unbind this texture for another creating texture
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0);
}

void Texture2DArray::Bind() const
{
   glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, this->ID);
}
```

Here is my Fragment Shader

```
#version 330 core

uniform sampler2DArray ourTexture;

in vec2 texCoord;

out vec4 FragColor;

void main(){
   // 1 (the layer number) just for testing
   FragColor = texture(ourTexture,vec3(texCoord, 1));
}
```

Here is my Vertex Shader

```
#version 330 core

layout (location = 0) in vec3 inPos;
layout (location = 1) in vec2 inTexCoord;

out vec2 texCoord;

uniform mat4 model;
uniform mat4 view;
uniform mat4 projection;

void main(){
    gl_Position =  projection * view * vec4(inPos,1.0f);
    texCoord = inTexCoord;
}
```

This my rendering result

[image]

**EDIT 1:**

I figured out that texture atlas doesn't work with texture array because it is a grid so OpenGl cannot decide where it should begin. So I create a vertical texture (18 x 72) and try again but it still all black everywhere.

[image]

I have checked binding the texture before using it.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When the 3 dimensional texture image is specified, then the depth has to be the number of images which have to be stored in the array (e.g. `imageCount`). The width and the height parameter represent the width and height of 1 tile (e.g. `tileW`, `tileH`). The layer should be 0 and the border parameter has to be 0. See [`glTexImage3D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage3D.xhtml). `glTexImage3D` creates the data store for the texture image. The memory which is required for the textures is reserved (GPU). It is possible to pass a pointer to the image data, but it is not necessary.

If all the tiles are stored in a vertical atlas, then the image data can be set directly:

```cpp
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, this->Internal_Format, 
             tileW, tileH, imageCount, 0,
             this->Image_Format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data);
```

If the tiles are in the 16x16 atlas, then the tiles  have to by extracted from the texture atlas and to set each subimage in the texture array. (`data[i]` is the imaged data of one tile). Create the texture image:

```cpp
glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, this->Internal_Format, 
             tileW, tileH, imageCount, 0,
             this->Image_Format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);
```

After that use [`glTexSubImage3D`](https://www.khronos.org/registry/OpenGL-Refpages/gl4/html/glTexSubImage3D.xhtml) to put the texture data to the data store of the texture object. `glTexSubImage3D` uses the existing data store and copies data. e.g.:

```cpp
for (int i = 0; i < imageCount; ++i)
{
    glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0,
        0, 0, i,
        tileW, tileH, 1,
        this->Image_Format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, data[i]);
}
```

Note, you've to extract the tiles from the texture atlas and to set each subimage in the texture array. (`data[i]` is the imaged data of one tile)

---

An algorithm to extract the tiles and specify the texture image may look as follows

```cpp
#include <algorithm>    // std::copy
#include <vector>       // std::vector
```

```cpp
unsigned char* data = ...; // 16x16 texture atlas image data
int tileW = ...;           // number of pixels in a row of 1 tile
int tileH = ...;           // number of pixels in a column of 1 tile
int channels = 4;          // 4 for RGBA

int tilesX = 16;
int tilesY = 16;
int imageCount = tilesX * tilesY;

glTexImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0, this->Internal_Format, 
             tileW, tileH, imageCount, 0,
             this->Image_Format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, nullptr);

std::vector<unsigned char> tile(tileW * tileH * channels);
int tileSizeX = tileW * channels;
int rowLen    = tilesX * tileSizeX;

for (int iy = 0; iy < tilesY; ++ iy)
{
    for (int ix = 0; ix < tilesX; ++ ix)
    {
        unsigned char *ptr = data + iy*rowLen + ix*tileSizeX;
        for (int row = 0; row < tileH; ++ row)
            std::copy(ptr + row*rowLen, ptr + row*rowLen + tileSizeX,
                      tile.begin() + row*tileSizeX);


        int i = iy * tilesX + ix;
        glTexSubImage3D(GL_TEXTURE_2D_ARRAY, 0,
            0, 0, i,
            tileW, tileH, 1,
            this->Image_Format, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, tile.data());
    }
}
```

Comment: Oh, it actually worked !!!! You really saved my life, I have been stuck in this problem for a week. Thank you so much !!!!

Comment: I believe that in the algorithm to extract tiles, `ptr` should be `data + iy*rowLen*tileH + ix*tileSizeX;` (multiply by `tileH`) because otherwise the start for copying will be offset by pixel row, not tile row. [before](https://i.imgur.com/L7OzFZF.png) and [after](https://i.imgur.com/0BI2v7w.png).

Comment: @Minebomber `rowLen = tilesX * tileSizeX` and `tileSizeX = tileW * channels`